# XML Schema complexType restrictions

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to add restrictions to the following complexType

```
     <xs:complexType>
       <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="FOO" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xs:annotation />
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                  <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                  <xs:maxInclusive value=""/>
                  <xs:attribute default="0" name="BAR" type="xs:int"/>
                  <xs:attribute name="accepted" type="xs:boolean"/>
                  <xs:attribute name="instance" type="xs:int"/>
                </xs:restriction>
              </xs:simpleContent>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
```

However I am getting the following error when trying to pass this through an XSD validator.

> When  is used, the base type must be a complexType
>   whose content type is simple, or, only if restriction is specified, a
>   complex type with mixed content and emptiable particle, or, only if
>   extension is specified, a simple type. 'decimal' satisfies none of
>   these conditions.

Can someone explain what is incorrect here and how to fix this?